# Can someone help me to organize this by methods as I do not understand how to:

Tags: java, methods

I have a program that lets the user select a temperature conversion and prints it out on a file stored locally. I made this program over a two week period so I adjusted it as i learned something new, but now i want it to be clear to any other programmer that reads it buy using methods.  Can someone help me to organize this by methods as I do not understand how to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

 public class convertOut
  {
   public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
     File file = new File ("E:\\Csc110\\Tempreture.txt ");
     Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);//Scanner
     PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter ("E:\\Csc110\\TempOut.txt " ); 
     String str;
     int loop = 10;

      while (loop <=10)
       {

     //  Separator 



      `
      // Print the invitation

         System.out.println ("For Celcius to Fahrenheit, Press 1"); // this has nothing to do with the code
         System.out.println ("For Fahrenheit to Celcius , Press 2 "); // no actual call to action
         System.out.println ("For fahrenheit to Kelvin, Press 3 "); // this has nothing to do with the code
         System.out.println ("For kelvin to Fahrenheit , Press 4"); // no actual call to action
         System.out.println ("For celcius to kelvin, Press 5"); // this has nothing to do with the code
         System.out.println ("For kelvin to 1celcius , Press 6 "); // no actual call to action


        char A;
         Scanner op = new Scanner (System.in);
         A = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
         if (A=='1') // C2f

     {



     while (inputFile.hasNext())
      { 
       str = inputFile.nextLine (); 
      int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
       double x = y * 9/5 + 32;


       outputFile.println (str + " degrees Celsius  converted to Fahrenheit  is : " + x + " Degrees" );
       }
       }
       else  if (A=='2') // f2c

     {



     while (inputFile.hasNext())
      { 
       str = inputFile.nextLine (); 
      int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
       double x = (y-32)*5/9;


       outputFile.println (str + " degrees Fahrenheit  converted to Celcius  is : " + x + " Degrees" );
       }
       }

       else  if (A=='3') // f2k

     {



     while (inputFile.hasNext())
      { 
       str = inputFile.nextLine (); 
      int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
       double x = (y+ 459.67) * 5/9;


       outputFile.println (str + " degrees Fahrenheit  converted to Kelvin  is : " + x + " Degrees" );
       }
       }

           else  if (A=='4') // k2f

     {



     while (inputFile.hasNext())
      { 
       str = inputFile.nextLine (); 
      int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
       double x = y *9/5 - 459.67;


       outputFile.println (str + " degrees Kelvin  converted to Fahrenheit  is : " + x + " Degrees");
       }
       }


                else  if (A=='5') // C2K

     {



     while (inputFile.hasNext())
      { 
       str = inputFile.nextLine (); 
      int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
       double x = y + 273.15;


       outputFile.println (str + " degrees Celsius  converted to Kelvin  is : " + x + " Degrees" );
       }
       }



                else  if (A=='6') // K2C

     {



     while (inputFile.hasNext())
      { 
       str = inputFile.nextLine (); 
      int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
       double x = y - 273.15 ;


       outputFile.println (str + " degrees Kelvin  converted to Celcius  is : " + x + " Degrees"  );
       }
       }




        outputFile.close();
        System.out.println ("Its Converted!\nDone!\nThe file name is: TempOut.txt ");

         double F ;
            System.out.println ("\n Enter 1 to or any other number to end. ");
            F = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
            if (F==1)
             {
              loop =1;
              }
               else 
                {
                 loop=12;
                 }



        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

few suggestions to improve your code: change if else to switch case and in each switch case, call corresponding method:
Sample method can be:

```
private void cToF(inputFile,outputFile){
while (inputFile.hasNext())
      { 
       str = inputFile.nextLine (); 
       int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
       double x = y * 9/5 + 32;
       outputFile.println (str + " degrees Celsius  converted to Fahrenheit  is : " + x + " Degrees" );
       }
       }
}
```

You can call this method in switch case as:

```
case '1' : cToF(inputFile,outputFile);
           break;
```

Comment if you need clarification.

Comment: Just saw the response, Thanks. It helps make everything more understandable but im having trouble initializing "outputFile"

Comment: what is the "trouble"?

Comment: I declared "inputFile" as a Scanner obj and "outputFile" as Printwiter in the main method, but now that i have them in parameters for the cToF  method as "(inputFile, outputFile)"  i get the following error : <identifier> expected

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769666/passing-filewriter-as-a-parameter-to-a-method